# QGIS layer in .svg or with a better resolution?

Tags: qgis, inkscape

I have a georeferenced layer, built from a nice map drawn with **[Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/)**. But when I convert it to *.png, *.jpg or *.tif, there is a pixelisation of the map. After georeferencing, it gives a pixelised map. I tried different definitions, sizes, etc but it always has much pixelisation.

How could I import the same map, but with nice contours, like in a *.svg file? I have thought about converting it into a shapefile, but I haven't found out if it is possible?

Comment: Could you add a picture to show the result?

Answer (score 6):

I am not aware of a direct SVG to shapefile converter, but there are some solutions to convert from SVG to kml:

http://github.com/pifantastic/rhok-philly/blob/master/svg2kml.py

http://bitbucket.org/tbrugz/kmlutils

Import of kml files is easy for QGIS.

---

Another possibility would be using DXF format. Inkscape can export to DXF, and QGIS can import that directly.